# Load script from CDN with ReSharper and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, tdd, resharper, phantomjs

I'm having trouble getting ReSharper to run qunit tests in Jasmine if they reference librarires (jQuery) hosted on a cdn.

```
/// <reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
```

does not work

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" />
```

Works

The issue for us is that we prefer to use libraries such as jQuery from the cdn and often do not have local copies. Is there an alternative way to tell ReSharper to tell PhantomJs that these resources should be loaded from the cdn?